# Подключение к локальной базе данных Java

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

необходимо создать и подключиться в бд postgresql разместив ее в папке с проектом. Просто прописав DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc:postgresql:./database.db) создать и подключиться не получается, пишет "сервер запросил парольную аутентификацию, но пароль не был указан".

Comment: Это невозможно. База данных PostgreSQL состоит из множества файлов, а не одного, должна размещаться в каталоге кластера и обслуживаться сервером.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, я выполняю лабораторную работу, преподаватель сказал, что база должна лежать рядом с проектом, выходит если невозможно, преподаватель ошибся

Comment: И сказал, что это должен быть обязательно PostgreSQL?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev к сожалению да( Отпишу преподу, что создание локальной бд невозможно. Благодарю за ответ!

Comment: [SQLite](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создать базу данных postgresql через jdbc с нуля невозможно. Перечитайте задание, что именно Вам необходимо "создать". Можно создать базу данных если локальный сервер инициализирован и Вы подключились с соответствующими привилегиями.

Относительно ошибки аутентификации, посмотрите мануал: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html
Вы можете передать пользователя и пароль дополнительными параметрами:

```
Connection db = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!

Comment: чтобы проинициализировать локальную базу в нужной папке необходимо задать путь в параметре, см https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-initdb.html